# Is there a way to access a template parameter outside the class?

Tags: c++, templates

So I was trying to make a function that is required to access the template argument of that class and I don't want to put that function in the class itself.
Here is a example:

```
  template <class Type>
  class Node
  {
      public:
          Type Value;
          Type* ptr_next;
    
  };

  void element_output(Node<  /*template argument of the class*/>  * head)
  {
      while(head!=NULL)
      {
          std::cout << head->Value << "\n";
          head = head->ptr_next;
        
      }
  }
```

I tried using a template for that function but that didn't work.
i was thinking of just overloading the Node template argument in the function parameter with all  the types.But i knew there was bound to be a error had to be a error that will occur.

So what I think could work is like a getter and setter for the template parameters similar with constructors and private memebers.

Comment: A function template **is** what you want `template <typename T> void element_output(Node<T>  * head)`

Comment: Correct that was what i meant .

Comment: As an aside, it's often a good idea to add something like `using type_t = Type;` inside your template class, so that you can easily extract that type when it isn't immediately obvious (ie, when you were passed a `Container<Key,Value>` and it uses `Node<pair<Key,Value>>` so you don't already have `Type` as a top-level type parameter)

Comment: somehow the question in the title is a little backwards. If you want to call the function with certain parameter, where is that parameter coming from ? If you create one via eg `Node<int> x;` you know its `Type`. It is `int`.

Comment: Whell if you would take a second of your time you would see that i mentioned it.@JasonLiam. Right here I tried using a template for that function but that didn't work"

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: `Type* ptr_next;` should be `Node* ptr_next;`

Comment: @Eljay Thats the mistake i fixed wich made the code not compile.Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Make the function template:

```
template <typename T>
void element_output(Node<T>* head)
{
    while (head != nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << head->Value << "\n";
        head = head->ptr_next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you didn't know about the function templates, you could explicitly create function overloads, say with

```
void element_output(Node<int>* head) { while ... }

void element_output(Node<double>* head) { while ... }

void element_output(Node<MyType>* head) { while ... }
```

Now you understand the natural templating mechanism

```
template<class Type> void element_output(Node<Type>* head) { while ... }
```

which you can specialize with `element_output<int>`, `element_output<double>`, `element_output<MyType>`...

Note that it is also possible to consider the argument to be a generic type,

```
template<class Type> void element_output(Type* head) { while ... }
```

and specialize with a `Node` type passed to `element_output<Node<int> >`, `element_output<Node<double> >`, `element_output<Node<MyType> >`...